# get textContent from string

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on an app, and I need to get the value that would be returned by the `textContent` property of a `div` if I inserted the string into the div (empty) with the `innerHTML` property.  This is for a preview for the user.  Obviously, I could do exactly that, but I can't have any scripts run from the parsed string of HTML.  For example, if the string contained `<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" onload="alert('hello')">`, the alert would show.

**Edit:** this is a file editing app, so the string could be anything.  The user could receive a malicious file and open it with the app and be hacked.

Comment: That's mighty confusing for me. All I can say is "Inline js is bad." https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Comment: If you're happy with limited browser support, you can use Mozilla's [HTML to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM) functionality. There is also a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOMParser), not sure about support for that either.

Comment: @RobG, That actually should work, we're already using a lot of features with very limited support.

Comment: You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is: where is this stuff that is previewed coming from?

More than likely, it's coming from the user's own browser.

There is no security risk in a user hacking their own browser.

The only time you need to worry yourself is when you are giving one user something that was submitted by another user. At this point, you have to worry about XSS attacks, and shoud trim accordingly. If this is the case, then please let me know. However, if not, then what you have is a sandbox, where it doesn't matter what the user does.

Comment: This is a file editing app, so the user could receive a file with malicious code, then the code could execute in his browser.

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with a security risk, the OP is only interested in the textContent and doesn't want inline scripts to run.

Comment: Actually it is mostly for security.